# Android React Native update error

Tags: android, react-native

I've released a native android app on Google Play.
Then I published (in beta mode) a new apk with higher version code that build with React Native. If my device has installed the old version (native app) and I pressed update the app on Play Store, it throws error -504 while installing. What is the problem when updating from native app to react native app?

[image]

Comment: still no solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this issue, the best way to see what is going on is to connect your device to ADB to view the log. The issue one of my co-workers was having was due to a change in the SDK version (previous version set to 23, new version set to 22).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by changing the **targetSdkVersion** higher than the previous apk **targetSdkVersion**